# what does it mean to make a process automatic (through programming)

Tags: process, cpu-word

For example, if I currently have to resize image on my own with photoshop, but am developing a c++ app to do it for me, what am I doing to the process?

I realize that the process will *be* automated. What I'm looking for is this (fill in the blank):

It will be much faster after I've _ _ _ _ _ _d the process which is currently manual but which will be automatic after I'm done with it.

I tried autonomize, but it isn't a word :(

Comment: You're looking for "automated".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Automated" ? You will automate a task that will then be automated.